# Wrong with mock_model in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec2

Here is the rspec code for testing show in customers controller:

```
it "'show' should be successful" do
  #category = Factory(:category)
  #sales = Factory(:user)
  #customer = Factory(:customer, :category1_id => category.id, :sales_id => sales.id)
  category = mock_model('Category')
  sales = mock_model('User')
  customer = mock_model(Category, :sales_id => sales.id, :category1_id => category.id)

  get 'show' , :id => customer.id
  response.should be_success
end
```

Here is the error in rspec:

```
CustomersController GET customer page 'show' should be successful
     Failure/Error: get 'show' , :id => customer.id
     ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound:
       Couldn't find Customer with id=1003
     # c:in `find'
     # ./app/controllers/customers_controller.rb:59:in `show'
     # ./spec/controllers/customers_controller_spec.rb:50:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

The rspec test passes with the real record created by Factory (see #ed in rspec code)

What's wrong with the mock? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spec is failing inside the controller's action which doesn't know anything about your mocks unless you told it explicitly.

Add this to your spec, before the `get` statement.

```
Customer.should_receive(:find).and_return(customer)
```

Comment: Got error:  6) CustomersController GET customer page 'show' should be successful
     Failure/Error: get 'show' , :id => customer.id
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `name' for :customer:Symbol
     # ./app/views/customers/show.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_customers_show_html_erb___69786027_34474944'
     # ./spec/controllers/customers_controller_spec.rb:51:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'. The line 15 in show.html.erb is :   <%= @customer.name %>

Comment: Why do you render views is controller specs? Well, if you want it to work, either create a mock with all model attributes or use a real object.

Comment: Does the mock generate all fields for the object? It has to fill in something for the faked object.    The real object works.

Comment: The mock is empty by default you have to tell it how to behave. It's normal it works with a normal object. Anyway, controller's spec are not the place to test views, you should disable this.

Comment: I see. I guess it would be easier by using the real object just as I did with the Factory if I want to test the view at the same time. Thanks.

Comment: BTW render_views is what recommended in Michael H.'s book. It seems convenient to test both controller and view together as long as with real objects when required.

Comment: Maybe but it's not in rspec book and it seems logic to split the two

Comment: For RSpec 3, I used the "expect to" method instead of "should receive": `expect(Customer).to receive(:find).and_return(customer)`